# mysql local installation mysql_install_db error

Tags: mysql

I am working on a *nix machine and I don't have `root` privileges.

I am trying to install mysql locally using this blogpost: http://www.thedance.net/~roth/TECHBLOG/localMySQL.html

However, I am stuck at `scripts/mysql_install_db` command.

When I run this command I get the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Neither host 'server.address.com' nor 'localhost' could be looked up with
/usr/bin/resolveip
Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct hostname.
If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script
with the --force option
```

On further digging, I found that adding `--basedir`resolves this issue. But then it generates the following errors:

```
$scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=.
Installing MySQL system tables...2015-07-17 01:38:15 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-07-17 01:38:15 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-07-17 01:38:15 0 [Note] ./bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25) starting as process 10281 ...
2015-07-17 01:38:15 10281 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
2015-07-17 01:38:15 10281 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/head.lower-test
2015-07-17 01:38:15 10281 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/head.lower-test
./bin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-07-17 01:38:15 10281 [ERROR] Aborting
2015-07-17 01:38:15 10281 [Note] Binlog end
2015-07-17 01:38:15 10281 [Note]
```

When I add `--datadir=myDataDir` (where myDataDir is a local directory) it generates following error:

```
$scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=. --datadir=myDataDir
Installing MySQL system tables...2015-07-17 01:40:54 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-07-17 01:40:54 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-07-17 01:40:54 0 [Note] ./bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25) starting as process 10329 ...
2015-07-17 01:40:54 10329 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
```

It is trying to access system level folders and because of the permission issues it is failing. How do I install it locally. And how do I setup the hostname?

Comment: manually install MySQL without sudo permission? hope you just use it as testing.

Comment: Similar case: http://superuser.com/questions/146337/install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu-10-04

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the following line in log:

> [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'

To solve it, add this flag to your command:

```
--lc-messages-dir="/some/path/you/can/access/without/sudo/"
```

Comment: Wow that's wild stuff. Nice job Raptor

Comment: Hi Raptor, I am getting a very strange behavior with this. lets say my installation dir is `$insdir`. In there I created a directory `messagedir` and passed that `lc-messages-dir=messagedir`. However, I am getting the following error: `Can't find messagefile $insdir/share/messagedir/errmsg.sys`. Notice how `messagedir` got appended by `share`. I also tried creating a directory named `messagedir` in share folder but still get the same error

Comment: I tried the absolute path and also had it surrounded in quotes. I am still getting the error but the path is correct now. Error: `Can't find messagefile $insdir/messagedir/errmsg.sys`

Comment: I also changed the permission of messagedir to 777 just in case.. still can't find messagefile error

Comment: I think I found the source of the issue. This command in the file `mysql-test/t/mysql_plugin.test` : `--copy_file $MYSQL_ERRMSG_BASEDIR/english/errmsg.sys $MYSQLD_BASEDIR/share/errmsg.sys`. I think $MYSQL_ERRMSG_BASEDIR doesn't exist